# How to test if a macro has the shape of a coordinate from TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

How can I know if a macro contains a coordinate, that is, in the sense of having the shape of a coordinate `num,num`.

What I want to do is to know if a given macro, `\pos`, has the shape (in sense of parsing) of a coordinate or not, and then do something in case it has it and do something else if the shape is not a coordinate. For example, I'm looking for a way of achieving:

```
\pos{0,0}
\ifcoordinate\pos
It is a coordinate
\else
It is not a coordinate
\fi
```

In that case, what `\ifcoordinate` should be? In other words, how can I know if the contents of the given macro are in the sequence: `number, coma, number`?.

*Note that I want to use this verification, later on, in some TikZ related code, so a TikZ related solution is appreciated.*

Comment: I think this is pretty hard the way you're describing.  TeX doesn't have a regular expression engine.  All of its ability to analyze strings comes from the actual macros themselves.  You can write a parser with macros (like TikZ does), but that seems more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: The TikZ coordinates have many different forms: `x,y`, `angle:radius`, `x,y,z`, `{2*4},{\x/2}`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version using [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) based on @egreg's examples:

This also yields

> YES
> NO
> YES

### Known Issues:

- `\IfDecimal` allows the decimal separator to be a dot or a comma.  Since we  uses a comma as a separator for the two numbers, the first coordinate can *not* use a comma as the decimal separator, but the second one can.  This inconsistency is not good so what is needed is a way to change the decimal separator for `xtring` to just be the period.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{wasCoordinate}
\newcommand*{\ifcoordinate}[3]{%
    \toggletrue{wasCoordinate}%
    \StrBefore{#1}{,}[\StringBeforeComma]
    \StrBehind{#1}{,}[\StringBehindComma]
    \IfDecimal{\StringBeforeComma}{}{\togglefalse{wasCoordinate}}
    \IfDecimal{\StringBehindComma}{}{\togglefalse{wasCoordinate}}
    \iftoggle{wasCoordinate}{#2}{#3}
}%

\begin{document}

\def\pos{1.23,1}
\ifcoordinate{\pos}{YES}{NO}

\def\pos{1.23}
\ifcoordinate{\pos}{YES}{NO}

\def\pos{1.23,-1}
\ifcoordinate{\pos}{YES}{NO}

\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\ifcoordinate{ m m m }
  {
   \bool_set_true:N \l_iscoord_bool
   \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpa_seq {,} {#1}
   \int_compare:nTF { \seq_length:N \l_tmpa_seq = 2 }
     {
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
        { \bool_if:NT \l_iscoord_bool { \iscoord_checkfornumber:n { ##1 } } }
     }
     { \bool_set_false:N \l_iscoord_bool }
   \bool_if:NTF \l_iscoord_bool {#2} {#3}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }
\cs_new:Npn \iscoord_checkfornumber:n #1
  {
   \regex_match:nnTF {\A \-? \d+ (\.\d+)? \Z}{#1}
     {\bool_set_true:N \l_iscoord_bool}
     {\bool_set_false:N \l_iscoord_bool}
  }
\bool_new:N \l_iscoord_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\def\pos{1.23,1}
\ifcoordinate{\pos}{YES}{NO}

\def\pos{1.23}
\ifcoordinate{\pos}{YES}{NO}

\def\pos{1.23,-1}
\ifcoordinate{\pos}{YES}{NO}

\end{document}
```

This will print

> YES
>   NO
>   YES

### Important change

Due to the changes to `expl3` made in Summer 2012, in the code above `\seq_length:N` should be replaced by `\seq_count:N`. Here's a new complete implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\ifcoordinate{ m m m }
 {
  \iscoord_main:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\bool_new:N \l__iscoord_iscoord_bool
\seq_new:N \l__iscoord_arg_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \iscoord_main:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
   \bool_set_true:N \l__iscoord_iscoord_bool
   \seq_set_split:Nnx \l__iscoord_arg_seq {,} {#1}
   \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__iscoord_arg_seq = 2 }
     {
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__iscoord_arg_seq 
        { \bool_if:NT \l__iscoord_iscoord_bool { \__iscoord_checkfornumber:n { ##1 } } }
     }
     { \bool_set_false:N \l__iscoord_iscoord_bool }
   \bool_if:NTF \l__iscoord_iscoord_bool {#2} {#3}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__iscoord_checkfornumber:n #1
  {
   \regex_match:nnTF {\A \-? \d+ (\.\d+)? \Z}{#1}
     {\bool_set_true:N \l__iscoord_iscoord_bool}
     {\bool_set_false:N \l__iscoord_iscoord_bool}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\def\pos{1.23,1}
\ifcoordinate{\pos}{YES}{NO}

\def\pos{1.23}
\ifcoordinate{\pos}{YES}{NO}

\def\pos{1.23,-1}
\ifcoordinate{\pos}{YES}{NO}

\end{document}
```